# Cisco SG200-26 - Can't change management VLAN

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan

I've purchased a new SG200-26 switch and upgraded it to the newest possible version:

[image]

I configured multiple VLANs - nothing special - however if I try now to change the management VLAN (as I did multiple times for my SG200-8 switches) I simply can't:

[image]

It doesn't matter if there is an interface up in the new management VLAN, I even configured a port as access port for the VLAN i want to use. The option just never gets editable. What may be the problem here?

The only way to 'force' the switch to use my VLAN as management VLAN is to set it as Default VLAN...

For me this looks like a bug in the firmware? Can anyone who has the same switch with the same version as me please check? As said, the same thing works flawlessly on my SG200-08.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: same issue here, you really need to change the default vlan and accordingly remove other ports

Answer (score 5):

It's a catch 22 if you are plugged into the management port - the switch won't let you change management VLAN if nothing is plugged into one of those ports.  It might be trying to prevent you to lock yourself out.  Plug another switch or device into a port with that VLAN and it will allow you to change.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is wickedly old and I apologize for reviving it, but if anyone else gets stuck in this spot: set the default IP address (192.168.1.254) to Static on the default VLAN and apply it.  Once that's done, the VLAN selection becomes active and you can switch to whatever management VLAN you want without having to set it as default.  The switch just needs a static IP address set before you can change it...setting it to the default gives you that access without immediately locking you out.

Answer (score -1):

Under the Default VLAN change to the VLAN managment you need and save reboot and you are done.